# How to add my html javascript popup to my php function?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I want to add my javascript popup code which is in an html file to my php function.
It's a visitor counter in php. I want when visitors visit the page 4 times my popup html js is displayed

Comment: > I want when visitors visit the page 4 times my popup html js is displayed

Why don't you do this in javascript instead of PHP? Would seem easier no?

Comment: it's an api that counts visitors. Maybe, Do you have any other options for linking the two codes? Maybe echo with html?

Comment: Don't think about HTML/JS in your PHP logic, do it in your Twig templates instead. You are probably looking for `app.session` (read the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#the-app-global-variable)).

Comment: Have you tried to use flash messages? [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#flash-messages)

Answer (score 0):

Do you just mean like this?

```
if ($increment == true) {
$compteur_actuel = $session->get('compteurClicsFreemium', 0);
$session->set('compteurClicsFreemium', $compteur_actuel+1);

if ($compteur_actuel > 4) {
    ?>
    <div>
        Your HTML code here
    </div>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: OP did not tell where the PHP code was located, this could get displayed anywhere. He should never do this in a Symfony application anyways.

Comment: If he doesn't want the div to appear where the code is executed then just store a boolean with the result and check the boolean where you want the div to appear...

Comment: Will be something in your style or javascript if it's disappearing since the php code will only run once

Comment: Well I can't see all your code but it could be something as simple as an animation in one of your css classes, just double check.

Comment: It's hard to help much without seeing the full project. Are the 2 code snippets located in different files? Is the PHP file separate to the full HTML page?

Comment: You'll need to have your php if statement as part of the main html page, so you will need to change your main page to a php file and embed the php code where you want the popup to appear within your html. Hope that helps.